# how can I suppress the table header from python-MySQL

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

how can I suppress the table header from the output, need something like MySQL -N or -ss, is there is something like that ?

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="py_jox"
)


mycursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
mycursor.execute("SELECT j, j_p FROM j_menue")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
          print(x)
```

the output is like :
{'j': 'apple', 'j_p': Decimal('10.20')}
{'j': 'pinaple', 'j_p': Decimal('15.10')}

where j & j_p is the "column names" that i want to remove.

so the desired output should be like :
{'apple' : Decimal('10.20')}
{'pinaple' :Decimal('15.10')}

Comment: Your script is only printing rows.  Whence is the source of the table header?

Comment: I've edited the code. this is the whole script